# WicketApplication class constructor getting called twice

Tags: tomcat, wicket

I am using wicket 6.20 and created a simple wicket application. It works fine on windows.  When I deploy it to Linux server under tomcat 8, I noticed that the  WicketApplication class constructor gets called twice on startup.  Similarly, the Init() method of WicketApplication also gets called twice. Any object created in the init() method results in 2 instances. So it's not just the log entries.

Because on windows it gets called only once, I think it could be tomcat configuration problem. Any help is appreciated

```
public WicketApplication(){
    logger.info("Creating  WicketApplication .... ");

    logger.info("Current Class Loader : " + this.getClass().getClassLoader().getClass().getName());
    logger.info("Parent Class Loader : " + this.getClass().getClassLoader().getParent().getClass().getName());


    logger.info("Done creating  WicketApplication .... ");
}
```

Log file -

INFO  - ContextLoader              - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1070 ms

INFO  - WicketApplication          - Creating  WicketApplication ....

INFO  - WicketApplication          - Current Class Loader : org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader

INFO  - WicketApplication          - Parent Class Loader : java.net.URLClassLoader

INFO  - WicketApplication          - Finished creating  WicketApplication ....

Above log entries get repeated again

INFO  - ContextLoader              - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 793 ms

INFO  - WicketApplication          - Creating  WicketApplication ....

INFO  - WicketApplication          - Current Class Loader : org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader

INFO  - WicketApplication          - Parent Class Loader : java.net.URLClassLoader

INFO  - WicketApplication          - Finished creating  WicketApplication ....

Tomcat server.xml has only one deployment of this webapp -

```html
<Host appBase="hellowebapps" autoDeploy="true" name="www.xyz.com" unpackWARs="true">
     <Context docBase="hello" path="" reloadable="false" sessionCookiePath="/"/>

 </Host>
```

Comment: It seems Tomcat sees two `WicketFilter`s in web.xml. Or two .war files with the same application but different names...

Comment: web.xml is exactly the same as what I have on Windows. It calls WicketApplication constructor only once on windows. Also  I am positive, it has only one deployment in server.xml and only one exploded app (no packaged war file)

Comment: I'd recommend you to download another Tomcat bundle (.tag.gz) and deploy the .war by just placing it in its `webapp` folder. If this helps then try to find what in `server.xml` (in your current Tomcat installation) leads to the problem.